# Remote Databasing

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I'm trying to use a web service to store/retrieve info from a remote SQL database.  For some reason empty strings are being inserted into the DB rather than the strings I want stored.

What I need is to store the strings deviceID & dateStamp if no entry in DB exists with deviceID.

DB table name is trials, and the columns are: _id | device_id | install_date

Note: Connects and interacts with database, just stores "" and "" instead of the strings.

Can someone please tell me why this is?  This is my first time I've tried this kind of thing so having a lot of trouble and trying to modify snippets I found to my needs.

Here is my java code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LicenseCheck extends Activity 
{
    String deviceID="",dateStamp="";       
    byte[] data;    
    HttpPost httppost;    
    StringBuffer buffer;    
    HttpResponse response;    
    HttpClient httpclient;    
    InputStream inputStream;    
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    
    {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        final String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);        
        deviceID = android_id; 
        Date now = new Date();
        dateStamp = String.valueOf(now);

        try 
        {                    
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();                    
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://99.57.234.12/Main.php");                    
            // Add your data                    
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);                   
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("device_id", deviceID));                    
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("install_date", dateStamp));                    
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));                     
            // Execute HTTP Post Request                    
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                    
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();                     
            data = new byte[256];                     
            buffer = new StringBuffer();                    
            int len = 0;                    
            while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )                    
            {                        
                buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));                    
            }                     
            inputStream.close();                
            } catch (Exception e) {                    
                Toast.makeText(LicenseCheck.this, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                
            }                
            if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')                
            {                    
                Toast.makeText(LicenseCheck.this, "working: " + buffer.toString() + ".", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Move_to_next();
                LicenseCheck.this.finish();
            } else {                    
                Toast.makeText(LicenseCheck.this, "Trial Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Move_to_next();
                LicenseCheck.this.finish();
            }                    
        }        
    public void Move_to_next()        
    {         
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainMenu.class));        
    }
}
```

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php 
    require_once('Connections.php'); 
    mysql_select_db($database_localhost,$localhost); 

    $device = $_POST['device_id'];
    $date = $_POST['install_date'];

    $query_search = "select * from trials where device_id = '".$device."'"; 
    $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);  



    if($rows --> 0) 
    { 
        echo "Y"; 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT device_id,install_date FROM trials WHERE device_id = '".$device."'");
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

        echo $row[0]; // device_id
        echo $row[1]; // install_date
        } else {
        echo "N";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO trials (device_id, install_date) VALUES ( '".$device."', '".$date."')") or die (mysql_error()); 
    }
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you have your answer already, but on the PHP side of things, you really should be using `mysqli_*` functions or `PDO` for making your database calls as `mysql_*` functions are being deprecated.  Also you need to sanitize your data before querying the database.  You are extremely vulnerable to SQL injection right now.

Comment: is it as simple as changing all the mysql_* to mysqli_*?

Comment: The is generally a pretty direct correlation between the mysql_* and mysqli_* functions in terms of the function signatures.  You should check the PHP site for full information.

Comment: ok thank you, once i get it working with the mysql_* commands ill look into the conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're posting:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DeviceID", deviceID));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DateStamp", dateStamp));
```

But you're looking for:

```
$device = $_POST['device_id'];
$date = $_POST['install_date'];
```

Your PHP is looking for variables in $_POST that haven't been set.

Comment: omg... am i really that dumb lol.  so do i just need to change "DeviceID" & "DateStamp" to match the post statements? ("device_id" & "install_date")

Comment: Yep - so long as it's consistent, it doesn't matter what you change. Sometimes it just takes a fresh pair of eyes to look at code....

Comment: made the change and now the device id stores but date still ""

Comment: Could you try a `var_dump($_POST)` in your PHP, so you can make sure that `install_date` is being set properly?

Comment: I would think you would use dateStamp = now.toString();

Comment: keep in mind I don't know PHP at all... using snippets. How do i do the var_dump?  (sorry for being a total nubsauce when it comes to PHP)

Comment: John D - `now.toString();` be better than what im doing now? (`String.valueOf(now);`)

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions - you can put it just before `$device = $_POST['device_id'];`

Comment: Added the var_dump where you said, and now it is storing both entries properly! Thank you sooo much!  Been banging my head on the wall for 3 days on this lol

Comment: One more issue with it tho... with the var_dump there it no longer finds the deviceid in the database (on app run instead of getting the working toast i always get the trial started one...

Comment: You can take the `var_dump` back out - it's only helpful while you're debugging.

Comment: Works like a charm now, thanks again. Marked as answer.  Now I just have to seperate the buffer results into strings and work with the resulting data, thats the easy part lol